# call PHP script after form submit

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have two separate processes and I am wondering how I can combine them.

1. I have a PHP email sign-up form which posts the users email address and other data into an SQL DB.
2. I have a sync PHP script API which once run adds all info from the SQL DB to a 3rd party site (mailchimp)

How can I combine them so once a new user adds their details, and the form is submitted the PHP API script runs. I did this, however it runs the script and the user has to wait until the API call is done:

```
$appUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$path = 'newsletter/mailchimp.php';//your path here
$appUrl = 'http://'.$appUrl.'/'.$path;

if (count($_POST)>0) echo file_get_contents($appUrl);?>
```

Comment: You can use ajax to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an HTML-element which you can bind your function to, like your form, button, checkbox or whatever. There's many different ways like `$("form").submit(function(){});`, `.click`, `.changed`. After that you can use the `$.post()` function to call the PHP-files.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonId").click(function(){
        $.post('phpfile1.php');
        $.post('phpfile2.php');
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks good, I have added a timeout function just incase there is a delay in writing to the DB

    setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newsletter").submit(function(){
    $.post('mailchimp.php');
    });
    });
    }, 10000);

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the content from a remote site, then you can't send it to the client before you've got it.

But in your example you are calling a URL on the local machine - if you include the file instead of calling it in a new HTTP request then you'll get a small improvement in speed.

If you don't need the content from the other URL, then call it from a shutdown function after your script generates the content flushes its buffers and exits.

Calling the second url via javascript is ot a good idea if the transaction spans both codesets - you're putting the user in control of the flow in your application.